# What is the best freeware app for Windows to mount EXT4 partitions (from a GPT 4TB Disk) as RW, safely without corrupting the EXT4 partition?

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, ext4, gpt

My Computer is set up as Dualboot Windows and Ubuntu. I have 1 OS drive, and 1 hard drive with a /backup partition (which has all my family photos and data) and it is ext4. Also note... it is EXT4, and it is GPT, and it is 4TB size.

Anyway, Windows can not mount the /backup ext4 partition. What software/freeware do you reccomend for Windows? Preferrably looking for someone with experiance using it for a long time and not have problems with EXT4 partition which is a 4TB, GPT Disk.

Comment: Best just to create another NTFS data partition for shared data. The Linux NTFS driver is more reliable and Windows drivers do not easily write data as they do not have the ownership & permissions that ext4 requires. Some do read ok.

Comment: Thanks, I did that but when Ubuntu writes data to the NTFS sometimes Windows Deleted it upon a checkdisk :(. This is why I only use ext3 or ext4 now because I dont want checkdisk to delete my photos. Does anyone know a safe way to mount ext4 partitions in Windows? Thanks so much

Comment: "sometimes Windows Deleted it upon a checkdisk". Doubt that. More logical: are using hibernation in between?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! The Paragon EXT Driver works perfectly (and copies files INTO ext4 which root:root permissions, so ext 4 is safely receiving those files).

Just in case anyone was wondering: In /etc/fstab for the /data ntfs partition I was using "0 0" as the mount permissions at the end. This caused Ubuntu to save files with invalid ntfs permissions into the /backupdata. Ubuntu can still read/write those files no problem, but when you boot into windows and do a chkdsk to check your files, it will delete those inodes and you will see checkdsk saying "invalid permissions on file abc.. found" as it scrolls. You should use "0 2" and the "ntfs-3g" in fstab to fix this. But I hate ntfs now because windows randomly does a checkdsk and deletes stuff, so I just leave my /backupdata as ext4 and this is better. Then the PARAGON driver below works to mount the ext4 but checkdsk will never run. Instead if you need it, ubuntu or fedora or any linux uses 'fsck -y /dev/sdb1' to fix if you need to fix files. :)

Here is the driver if anyone needs it:

> Ext for Windows | PARAGON Software Group - Ext2 / Ext3 ...
>   **www.paragon-software.com/home/extfs-windows/** Paragon Software Group
>   Paragon ExtFS for Windows is a special utility which allows you to get
>   full access to Ext2 / Ext3 / Ext4 in Windows. With Paragon Ext for
>   Windows, you can work ... ‎Download - ‎Product Tour - ‎ExtFS für
>   Windows